# SqlServer SMO Scripting.ScriptingError event handler not firing

Tags: sql-server, database, smo

I have a SQL Sever 2008 R2/64-bit database server for which I'm writing some fairly basic scripting utilities with the Sql Server Management Objects (SMO). My project is a 32-bit VS2010 executable written in C#.

Most of the effort has been fairly simple and successful. The only problem I'm having is in the firing of my custom event handler that should be called in response to a Scripting Error.

The `Scripter` object exposes a `ScriptingError` event, which I have attempted to leverage thusly:

```
//srv contains a valid server name
Scripter scrp = new Scripter(srv);

//scrp_ScriptingError is my handler
scrp.ScriptingError += new ScriptingErrorEventHandler(scrp_ScriptingError);
```

My handler is declared thusly:

```
   static void scrp_ScriptingError(object sender, ScriptingErrorEventArgs e)
   {
       // my handler goes here, just printing e.Current.Urn to the console
       // This is merely representative, have had other things here, but
       // the handler never fires
       Console.WriteLine(e.Current.Value);
   }
```

All this compiles cleanly.

My code is invoked via simple `scrp.Script(urns);` where `urns` is just an array of the database objects being scripted out. Nothing fancy:

```
    try
    {
        sc = scripter.Script(urns);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        WriteLog(String.Format("Failure during scripting: {0}: Inner exception message (if any): {1}",e.Message,((e.InnerException==null)?"[None]":e.InnerException.Message)));
    }
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName,true))
    {
        foreach(String currentLine in sc)
        {
            file.WriteLine(currentLine);
            file.WriteLine("GO");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that, no matter what I've tried so far, when errors occur during scripting, my ScriptingError handler never fires.

Even in debug mode within VS2010, when I set a breakpoint within the handler, and fire my scripting code, and know an error will occur, only an exception will be thrown, but the breakpoint in my ScriptingError handler never trips.

I'm in trees-for-forest mode now, not sure what I've done wrong. Am I expecting the wrong things for the ScriptingError handler?

I have searched the MSDN docs on the SMO objects and found virtually nothing on ScriptingError handlers other than the basic API calls themselves, and precious few examples on the Internet. It seems incredibly simple and straightforward to me - just assigning an event handler to the event - but there's some battery-not-included notice I've failed to note.

Pointers to my error are greatly appreciated, with a polite request for minimal brickbats if the error is exceptionally stupid on my part :)

Comment: can you give an example for the kind of exception that is thrown?

Comment: Well, it never really matters - whatever exception gets thrown, no ScriptingError event fires. Its typically always a simple "Script failed for server xxxx", with an inner exception of something like: "property HeaderText is not availble for procedure xxxxx", another time it was "Could not retrieve dependencies," both of which were fixable with different options on the Scripter object. I just expected my ScriptingError handler to fire when they occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not at a pc right know, but I think you should try to set the [ContinueScriptingOnError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.continuescriptingonerror%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) option. Otherwise there would be no reason for SMO to invoke the event, but rather through an exception instead.

Comment: That's whqt I thought, but setting this option to true/false makes no difference. Thank you for taking the time to offer the answer nonetheless!

Comment: Well, dude, from the darkness of Just Trying It Again For the Heck Of It, I changed it to false, recompiled, still didn't work, changed it back to true, voila, it magically started working. *sigh*. Happy answer points for you! :)